# Can I access the size of the delayed_jobs queue from a Heroku client?

Tags: heroku, delayed-job

I have a [Heroku gem](https://github.com/heroku/heroku) client setup to access/set variables in my Heroku app from outside of it.

```
heroku_client = Heroku::Client.new(ENV['HEROKU_USER'], ENV['HEROKU_PASSWORD'])
queue_depth = heroku_client.info(ENV['APP_NAME'])[:HTTP_X_HEROKU_QUEUE_DEPTH].to_i
workers = heroku_client.info(ENV['APP_NAME'])[:workers].to_i
```

From within the Heroku app, I can get the size of the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) queue with:

```
Delayed::Job.count
```

Is there anyway I can access that queue size from the external Heroku client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a one off console command via the Heroku client: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/client.rb#L209

So something like heroku_client.console(ENV['APP_NAME'], "Delayed::Job.count")

You can also run rake tasks via theHeroku client.